# Maven Antrun: How to enable skipped task?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a maven-project where "need" to start a program with antrun (the need isn't reflected by the example below). By default antrun should be disabled as the example shows.

```
<execution>
  <id>default-cli</id>
  <phase>test</phase>
  <configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
  <tasks>
    <delete dir="target/dependencies" />
    <copy todir="target/dependencies" flatten="true">
  </tasks>
</execution>
```

But in some of the automated environments we would like to enable it again. So I expected

```
mvn test -Dmaven.antrun.skip=false
```

to do the trick but that maven.antrun.skip only seems to work to disable the task and not to enable it again. The log just says "Skipping Antrun execution".

I also tried to run the task with

```
mvn antrun:run@default-cli
```

but the message stays the same.

So, how to disable antrun as default to be able to run it ad-hoc when needed?

Java8, Maven3.6, Antrun1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your own property in properties like

```xml
<properties>
   <skip-default-cli>true</skip-default-cli>
</properties
```

Then, inside the execution, set `<skip>${skip-default-cli}</skip>`.

On command line, you add `-Dskip-default-cli=false` to activate the run.